# How do you update text shown by innerHTML in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I assign a variable to the innerHTML, and when the variable gets changed, the display on-screen doesn't. How do I make it so it does change whats displayed when the variable changes? Answers in HTML 5 please.

```html
<script>
  var a = 10;

  function funk() {
    a = a - 1;
  }
</script>

<p id="oof">
  <script>
    document.getElementById("oof").innerHTML = a;
  </script>
</p>
<p onclick="funk()">change var</p>
```

Comment: And what if the answer is in JavaScript? JS is literally not HTML.  

Answer (score 3):

Make the change inside the function `funk`. One assignment doesn't bind the `innerHTML` to the value of `a` as it changes, it's a one time assignment:

```html
<script>
  var a = 10;

  function funk() {
    a = a - 1;
    document.getElementById("oof").innerHTML = a;
  }
</script>

<p id="oof">
  <script>
    document.getElementById("oof").innerHTML = a;
  </script>
</p>
<p onclick="funk()">change var</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you assign the value to the innerHTML, you only do it once. When the `a` variable is changed later, that innerHTML value doesn't know about it. What you need is a way to update that "oof" div whenever the button gets clicked, for example by adding the innerHTML assignment into the `funk()` function like so:

```
oof = document.getElementById("oof");
function funk() {
  oof.innerHTML = --a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Without getElementById if one element has id , JavaScript create variable I'd name and assign variable  to element

```
let a = 10;


  function funk() {
    a -=1;
    view();
  }


function view()
{

  oof.innerHtML=a;

}
</script>

<p id="oof">

</p>
<p onclick="funk()">change var</p>
```

Comment: Do you really need the view() function? It's only one line and used in one place

Comment: Because you next time update view of html ...what is the god object ?

Comment: God object is create everything but not true for software .next time view function extra make something ,look at single prenciple for software

Comment: I meant that instead of calling view() you could just say oof.innerHTML = a; and it would be shorter and without additional complications

Comment: If your create true structure you must create view function because u can call everywhere in any where ..if inside funk u not call again ..one function must be  callable again again

Comment: Look at MVC pattern in js

Comment: Maybe can required update of element ! If required I will call view that is enough ...

Comment: I know that you should replace the document.getElementById("oof") with a variable declared at the top; what I wanted to tell you is that the view() function is just an unnecessary abstraction because you can just replace the function call with the content of it and it would work the same way. If you had to call the function again, why don't you just repeat the innerHTML assignment? It is only one line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198888/discussion-between-volper-and-dilo-surucu).